# How can I align text/images from an adapter?

Tags: android, layout, adapter

I've been playing around a lot with this but I can't seem to make it work. I want to move the icon to the furthest right of the screen as possible but I can't find how to. Usually, something like this would work but for some reason it doesn't. I think it's something to do with the adapter displaying multiple rows of the xml rather than just one.

rowlayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@+id/label"
    android:textSize="20px" >
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:text="Loaded"
    android:textSize="20px" >
</TextView>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="22px"
    android:layout_height="22px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
    android:layout_marginRight="10px"
    android:layout_marginTop="4px"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
     >
</ImageView>

 </LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
            "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
            "Linux", "OS/2" };
    MySimpleArrayAdapter adapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(this, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

}
```

MySimpleArrayAdapter:

```
 public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private final Context context;
private final String[] values;

public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
    super(context, R.layout.rowlayout, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    textView.setText(values[position]);
    String s = values[position];
    if (s.startsWith("iPhone")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.yes);
    } else {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.no);
    }

    return rowView;
    }
 }
```

Thanks for any help you can offer

edit: woops, by icon i meant image

Comment: use RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout and give ImageView the property android:alignParentRight=true

Comment: thanks for the advice, i'll give it a whirl tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this something you'd like to achieve?:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Label"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="22dp"
    android:layout_height="22dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/icon"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/label"
    android:text="Loaded"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Please be advised that you should never use px as a dimension to whatever. Instead, use dp for sizes like width, height, margins or paddings, and always use sp for text sizes!!!

Also, for a way better performance, please check out the ViewHolder pattern for the ListView's adapter. This refers to your code in the adapter's getView() method.

Does this help?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i'll check tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

you have to use RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@+id/label"
    android:textSize="20px"/>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/load"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
          android:layout_below="@id/label"
    android:text="Loaded"
    android:textSize="20px" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="22px"
    android:layout_height="22px"
          android:layout_below="@id/label"
    android:layout_marginTop="4px"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
     />
    </RelativeLayout>
```